# on click of the selected div its text should be shown on next page

Tags: php

This is part of my page; what I want is when user selects php then on next page in title php should be shown

```
<div class="webdev">
<hr />
<div id="tab"><h4><a href="../pages/webdev.php" target="_blank">PHP </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Duration:30 mins</h4></div>
<hr />
<div id="tab"><h4><a href="../pages/webdev.php" target="_blank">Wordpress </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Duration:30 mins</h4></div>
<hr />
<div id="tab"><h4><a href="../pages/webdev.php" target="_blank">Joomla </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Duration:30 mins</h4></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post what you have tried (sample code,desired output etc) when posting a quetion

Answer (score 0):

Pass it via URL parameters:

```
<a href="next.php?category=php">PHP</a>
```

Then in next.php read it via $_GET['category'].

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by use of query strings

just set these as Hyperlinks as

```
<a href="nextPage.php?action=php">PHP</a>
<a href="nextPage.php?action=wq">Wordpress</a>
<a href="nextPage.php?action=joo">Joomla</a>
```

> nextPage.php

```
if(isset($_GET['action']))
{
   $action = $_GET['action'];
     if($action=='php')
        {// Your code}
       else if ($action=='wp')
           {
           }
          else if($action='joo')
             {

             }
}
```